# Warning while taking input into an int array

Tags: c

```
int array[100], i;

for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
  scanf("%d", &array[i]);
}
```

This is giving me following warning

```
warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat]
```

**Edit**

[Actual code](http://codepad.org/ZG6Bsmb5):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void main()
{
  int array[100], n, j, ctr = 0, flag = 0;
#define FIX(i) ((array[i]==i)?1:0)
#define CHECK(i,num) ((array[i]==num)&&(array[num]==i)?1:0)
  scanf("%d", n);
  printf("\n");
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
  {
    scanf("%d", &array[j]);
    if (array[j] >= n)
    {
      printf("out of range\n");
      return;
    }
    else
    {
      if (FIX(j) == 1)
        ctr++;
      else if ((array[j] < j) && ((CHECK(j,array[j])) == 1) && (flag == 0))
      {
        ctr = ctr + 2;
        flag = 1;
      }
    } //end if
  } //end loop

}
```

Comment: I don't get such warning.

Comment: This warning is not from what you're compiling. However this will come from `scanf("%d",array[i]);`

Comment: are you sure you wrote the right code here? can you split it up into separate lines for better readability?

Comment: this is my actual code http://codepad.org/ZG6Bsmb5

Comment: How is that your actual code?  You don't have any includes at the top.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So based on your [actual code](http://codepad.org/ZG6Bsmb5):

Fix:

```
scanf("%d",&n);
           ^ Use ampersand sign
```

You need to use address of variable

Answer (score 0):

To take input to any variable you must use "&" operator to get the input assigned to that memory address. So in your program you should change scanf("%d",n) to scanf("%d",&n). That means you are assigning integer type data to an integer type memory address.